# Refreshing cart buttons with AJAX in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to swap the button on a custom mobile mini-cart using AJAX and `$fragments` but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing?

**Functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'mobile_add_to_cart_fragment' );
 
function mobile_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    ob_start(); 
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons spaced"><?php /*do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' );*/ 
          if ( $cart_count !== 0 ) {
             woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout(); 
           } 
           else { 
            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary all-caps fw-600" data-dismiss="modal">DONE</button>';
          } ?></p><?php
 
    $fragments['.mini-cart-btn-ajax'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
 }
```

**Cart PHP file**

```
<div class="modal-footer modal-footer-centered">
        <?php $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>
        <div class="text-center mini-cart-btn-ajax">
          <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons spaced"><?php /*do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' );*/ 
          if ( $cart_count !== 0 ) {
             woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout(); 
           } 
           else { 
            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary all-caps fw-600" data-dismiss="modal">DONE</button>';
          } ?></p>
        </div>
</div>
```